# Can someone correct my configuration files to start my own PTR record for mail server

Tags: centos, dns, bind, hosting-services

I have iredmail server running on centos 8 i need to set my own PTR record here is below my configuration files it will be highly appreciated if someone correct this to start PTR record

/etc/named.conf

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
    //listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
    //listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
    recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
    allow-query     { localhost; };

    /* 
     - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
     - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable 
       recursion. 
     - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access 
       control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
       cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification 
       attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
       reduce such attack surface 
    */
    recursion no;

        dnssec-enable yes; 
    dnssec-validation yes;

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

    /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
    include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";


zone "vimtrading.com" {
      type master;
      file "/var/named/named.vimtrading.com";
      allow-query { any; };
      allow-transfer { 90.148.141.85; };
};
```

/var/named.vimtrading.com

```
; zone file for vimtrading.com

; default TTL for this zone
$TTL 3H
@       IN SOA  ns1.vimtrading.com. hostmaster.vimtrading.com. (
                                2020111220  ; serial
                                        1D  ; refresh
                                        1H  ; retry
                                        1W  ; expire
                                        3H)     ; Negative cache TTL

; Name servers for this domain
        IN      NS      ns1.vimtrading.com.
        IN      NS      ns2.vimtrading.com.

; Mail server for this domain. A small number (0) implies higher priority.
        IN      MX     0       mail.vimtrading.com.
        IN      MX     10      mail2.vimtrading.com.

; A records
www     IN      A      3.137.158.1
@       IN      A      3.137.158.1
ns1     IN      A      3.137.158.1
ns2     IN      A      3.137.158.1
mail    IN      A      3.137.158.1
mail2   IN      A      3.137.158.1

; AAAA records 
mail    IN      AAAA   2001:16a2:cf3b:f00:7c0f:8033:c42:8da5

; CNAME records  
ftp     IN      CNAME  www.vimtrading.com

;TXT records (SPF, DKIM, DMARC, etc)
@               IN      TXT     "v=spf1 mx ~all"
dkim._domainkey IN      TXT     ("v=DKIM1; k=rsa; "
          "v=DKIM1;t=s;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDiiweYt0xL3x2EuGUCpm8p35C10x7i25jHR66V7/PDSCVouLOrb8UlNkx/R5WQnflic9+TOR8+O+tR/xqnIqC/011cK/y+wiwa0n9/c5c1tqc8HJlCSy2Ym4h3KYflVc6AwBwdlrX6Sx4VdjQUsrcR8NWU6DoQOZsAdzZ+QbVYmwIDAQAB")

_dmarc          IN      TXT     "v=DMARC1; p=none; pct=100; rua=mailto:dmarc-reports@vimtrading.com.”
```

/etc/named.rfc1912.zones

```
// named.rfc1912.zones:
//
// Provided by Red Hat caching-nameserver package 
//
// ISC BIND named zone configuration for zones recommended by
// RFC 1912 section 4.1 : localhost TLDs and address zones
// and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6303
// (c)2007 R W Franks
// 
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
// Note: empty-zones-enable yes; option is default.
// If private ranges should be forwarded, add 
// disable-empty-zone "."; into options
// 

zone "localhost.localdomain" IN {
    type master;
    file "named.localhost";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "localhost" IN {
    type master;
    file "named.localhost";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "named.loopback";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "named.loopback";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "named.empty";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

Comment: Unless you're authoritative for your reverses (and you almost certainly aren't) running your own server will not let you 'set your own PTR record'.

Comment: That IP address is owned by Amazon, so they run the authoritative servers for the 158.137.3.in-addr.arpa reverse zone, and you have to ask them to create the PTR record for you. It looks like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/reverse-dns-for-ec2s-elastic-ip-addresses/) describes the relevant procedure.

Comment: sorry my bad i forget to change the ip my ip is 87.101.216.99

Comment: Same thing applies, then, except you need to contact Integrated Telecom Co. Ltd or whoever your reseller is